# Are there any archeological finds or primary source drawings of the Chinese "blade shaped" bamboo-copter or rotary fans?

Tags: china, technology, archaeology

[Bamboo-copter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo-copter) was a toy in China, dated to 400 BC. A [Rotary Fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_inventions#R) also existed in China around 180 AD. I'm interested in both of those things, as they work on the exact same principle.

Do we have any archaelogical finds of them? Absent that, are there any detailed drawings of them dating from those periods?

I can find tons of pictures of these things online, but they all look like modern versions. I want to see original versions, because it's very critical to see **the blade shape.** In particular, I want to know if the blades were plain rectangles, or had some curves in them, especially washout twist like you see in modern propellers.

Comment: `dating from those periods` There's no evidence the Bamboo Dragonfly existed in "400 BC". This looks like a typo for 400 CE.

Comment: @Semaphore If it is, it's a typo on Wikipedia too. The article has a cite for it, but it's some book I don't have.

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting whoever wrote that on Wikipedia made a typo. Regardless, the first attestation to the bamboo dragonfly is the early 4th century document cited on Wikipedia, so there's no earlier primary source.

Comment: @Semaphore - Might be worth going to the WP page's "talk" page and making that point there too.

Comment: 400 BC is also in the cited book _Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics with CD Extra
By Gordon J. Leishman_
"The ideas of vertical flight can be traced back to early Chinese tops, a toy first used about 400 BC." - page 6

Comment: The answer's rotator is like blade, isn't it?

Comment: @KentaroTomono Yes but im looking for archaeological finds OR primary source drawings, as the title says. The answer shows a model that appears to be a replica. If there is a drawing of it dated to that period, please post it.

Answer (score -1):

The attached image is a Bamboo-copter of [Jin Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(266%E2%80%93420)).
The related [exhibition](http://news.cnhubei.com/shehui/p/10604283.html) can be accessed in JiangHanGuan Museum at Wuhan, Hubei province, China.
[image]

Comment: Interesting, but I see no date given for that object, rather the statement that for all the toys in the exhibition "The time span ranges from the late period of the new era to the 1980s."

Comment: Please refer the second last paragraphy of [link](http://news.cnhubei.com/shehui/p/10604283.html). It's said this bamboo-coper was made about 1700 years ago between 266 to 420 AD.

Comment: @BobLew: I dunno, it looks mighty pristine for a 1700 year old piece of wood to me. Judging by the Google translation, the link says the things *appeared* in the Jin dynasty; not that it's an authentic one. Compare with e.g. [this statue](https://nyshowplace.com/antique-chinese-carved-wood-statue-of-guanyin.html) from just a few centuries later. It's almost certainly an imitation built for the purpose of the exhibition.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: The statue has nothing to do with the bamboo-copter, apart from being 1500 years old. If you compare the picture in the answer and that of the statue I linked to, you'll see that the statue actually looks that old; the bamboo-copter does not.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy yeah, because bamboos are vulnerable to wind, rainfall, sand and so on. What do you expect to them from the point of view of the reservation?

Comment: @KentaroTomono: I suspect you're not understanding what prompted my comment. The answer claims the photo is an artifact from the Jin Dynasty. The very first comment by Aaron questions whether it is authentic. OP seems to reject the idea it's some kind of modern example. I agree with Aaron. And then for some reason you jump in and the whole discussion goes haywire and turns incomprehensible. Sigh.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I read all the comments by Bob Lew. He was not saying such a thing. Only he is saying, "the bamboo copter was made around 200-400 AD, not BC, and the image is from the Chinese exhibition." Why would you think the Chinese exhibition only can present replica? ( Btw, I bet Bob Let can read and understand Chinese perfectly. )

Comment: From what I can see, the exhibition's webpage only claims that bamboo dragonflies in general were made 1700 years ago. It makes no such claim about the example in the photo. The photo's  caption merely reads "bamboo dragonfly".

Comment: @robert, please move all the comments into the answer.  The answer should contain all that you know without reference to comments.